# Create custom flat switch android

Tags: android, xml, android-switch

I want to make one custom switch as shown below.

[image]

[image]

I have created two drawable resource for that one is switch_bg and another is tracker_bg.

switch_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_on" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_off" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_on" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_off" />
</selector>
```

tracker_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tracker" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tracker" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tracker" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tracker" />
</selector>
```

and in main xml I put following code.

```
<Switch
  android:id="@+id/switch1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:checked="true"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
  android:thumb="@drawable/switch_bg"
  android:track="@drawable/track_bg"/>
```

Please guide me What I am doing wrong or What things are missing from my side.

Comment: seems like your code is fine

Comment: Yes, But I didnt get desire result from above code.

Comment: @drawable/thumb_on and @drawable/thumb_off is image file or xml ?

Comment: it is an image file.

Comment: As i know, you should create a generic drawable and set it as a drawable, then experince with thumb and tracks.

Comment: https://github.com/Leaking/SlideSwitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample it may help you.[Click here](https://github.com/Leaking/SlideSwitch)